# How do i access the constant field using instant reference using linq in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having a model like below...

```
   public class Class1
   {
      public const string Example = "Example";
      public string Name { get; set:}
   }
```

And one more model named as "Class2" in which "Class1" acts as virtual like below...

```
   public class Class2
   {

      public int Id{get; set;}

      public virtual Class1 class1obj {get; set;}
      piblic int class1objId {get; set;}

   }
```

Now I have one service method to get the values hold by model "Class2", mentioned below

```
   GetClass<T>();
```

now, I planned to get data using below code:

```
    var data = GetClass<Class2>(s => s.class1obj.Example == "Example1");
```

But, When i type the above code and i tried to access the constant like s.class1obj.Example it throws error and intellisense also shows only the "Name" property and did not shows the const Example declared in "Class1" ? Why, I am not able to access the constant field ? I am in learning process, please can any one help me on this...

Comment: Obviously you can't access constants via instance. It needs to be accessed via classname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access constants through an instance. You need to use the class name. For example:

```
var ex = Class1.Example;
```

An alternative would be to add an access property to your class:

```
public Class1
{
    public const string Example = "Example";

    public string ExampleConst { get { return Example; } } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constant fields are implicitly static. This means that they belong not to an instance, but to a type. Therefore, to access the constant field you need to access not a class instance, but a type object, just as you would do with a static field or method. In your case, this means that you access `Class1.Example` and not `class1obj.Example`.

Answer (score 1):

Example is a constant, think of it as a property of the class rather than of the object instance.

To access it you'd call

```
var val = Class1.Example;
```

and so

```
var data = GetClass<Class2>(s => Class1.Example == "Example1");
```

However this doesn't make sense to me (it will ALWAYS return true as it's a constant). I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do in your lamba so it's difficult to advise any further...